# How to bind a WiFi to a computer in network with multiple access points with same SSID?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

In our college premises we have configured multiple WiFi AP with same ssid and same authentication. At this point, the computer choose the best Access Point with good signal. The problem is, sometimes pc automatically re-connect to a weak AP when there is a AP with good signal. i want to bind a computer to a particular Access Point other than MAC FILTERING in AP.Since the situation changes every time. Is it possible to bind a pc to a particular AP by assigning mac addr of AP.

Client Operating System: Windows 7

Current Network Structure

GATEWAY(1) > ROUTER> SWITCH > AP*3

Comment: What OS are you using? Kinda important....

Comment: Sorry. Windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: Which WiFi adapter (make and model) are you using?  In my experience forcing a WiFi adapter to bind to a specific AP relies on the driver of the WiFi adapter, and not all WiFi adapter (drivers) can support it.

Comment: Some network software from NIC/laptop/motherboard manufacturers allow this, but (to my knowledge) there isn't a way to get Windows to do it.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, cheat.

You can use a [Ubiquiti Nanostation M or Nanostation Loco M (smaller, cheaper)](https://www.streakwave.com/items.asp?Cc=NanoStation-M) as a bridge between Ethernet and the wifi network.  Those are 802.11n devices - the M2 is 2Ghz, the M5 is 5Ghz.

Additionally, they have very good directional antennas for the price, so you'll get a much better signal with them than your laptop's built-in antenna, though you'll have to point them at the AP.

So, your side is

Your computer <--- ethernet cable ---> Nanostation <---- wifi ----> AP

In particular, to set this up

- Station mode
- AirMax is OFF (it's not for talking to a normal AP)
- "Lock to AP" is the option to bind a specific AP's MAC address.

  - Don't try this first; first point the Nanostation at each AP in turn, to find the one with the best signal, and then simply point it at the correct AP; the Nanostation's directionality may be enough to stop the roaming.
- Turn down the Nanostation's output power; it's going to be far more than is needed, and may actually cause problems due to reflection or overpowering the AP's receiver.

Be warned; the current batch of Ubiquiti AirMax AC gear is not for talking to consumer 802.11ac.  The M series, however, talks to normal 802.11n just fine.